# A challenge: How to reorganize the horizontal hline in the Table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I have done this table:

[image]

But I wish to have the left column with labels 1 in the Class, all join together into a single block. And similarly, I wish to have the left column with labels 2 in the Class, all join together into a single block. In short, we only need to show 1 just once, and 2 just once.

Here is my Tex code:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c||c| c|} 
\hline
Class \; & \;  math  & \; type\\ \hline
 1\; & \;  spin  & \; a \\ \hline
 1\; & \;  statistics & \;   b \\ \hline
 1\; & \; string  & \;  c \\ \hline
2 \; & \;   spin  & \; d \\ \hline
2\;  & \;  statistics & \; e \\ \hline
2\;  & \;  string  & \; f \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{  }
\label{}
\end{table}
```

Thank you for all experts, if there is any comment and answer please!

Comment: Hi, It's easier when you provide a fully working MWE including usepackage and all that.

Comment: Add `\usepackage{multirow}` and use something like `\multirow{3}*{1}`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is as good a time as any to flex your [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) muscles:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Class} & \textbf{Math} & \textbf{Type} \\
  \midrule
  1 & spin       & a \\
    & statistics & b \\
    & string     & c \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
  2 & spin       & d \\
    & statistics & e \\
    & string     & f \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Also consider viewing this informative graphic ([source](http://darkhorseanalytics.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/ClearOffTheTableMd.gif)):

[image]

Comment: It seems like the \toprule, \midrule do not work for documentclass of {revtex4}, such as \documentclass[aps]{revtex4}. Do you know how to fix it, Werner?

Answer (score 3):

Use `\cline` instead of `\hline` (I deleted the spces `\;` to make the example quickly compilable):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c||c| c|} 
\hline
Class  &   math  &  type\\ 
\hline
 1 &   spin  &  a \\ 
\cline{2-3}
  &   statistics &    b \\ 
\cline{2-3}
  &  string  &   c \\ 
\hline
 2  &    spin  &  d \\ 
\cline{2-3}
   &   statistics &  e \\ 
\cline{2-3}
   &   string  &  f \\ 
\hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{  }
\label{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Nor related, but try not to use a so restrictive placement specifier as `[!h]`; either use a less restrictive option or don't use any at all (even better).

Comment: Yes, thanks, I thought it is simple, but just cannot recall the \cline. +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

For your problem,

Try this

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabular}{|c||c| c|} 
\hline
Class \; & \;  math  & \; type\\ \hline
multirow{3}{*}{1} \; & \;  spin  & \; a \\ \hline
 \; & \;  statistics & \;   b \\ \hline
 \; & \; string  & \;  c \\ \hline
multirow{3}{*}{2} \; & \;   spin  & \; d \\ \hline
 \;  & \;  statistics & \; e \\ \hline
 \;  & \;  string  & \; f \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\caption{  }
\label{}
\end{table}
```

untested because no fully working MWE.